# Pass attributes to ActiveRecord before_validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

ActiveRecord's `validates_each` method supports multiple attributes:

```
validates_each :foo, :bar, :baz do |record, attr, value|

    # logic here

end
```

Is there a way to do this with ActiveRecord callbacks?

```
before_validation [:foo, :bar, :baz] :do_something

...

protected

  def do_something(*args)

    args.each do |a|

      # logic here

    end

  end

...
```

** edit **

`:foo`, `:bar`, `:baz` are URLs.  I want to 'normalize' them (add 'http://' to the start if it's missing) prior to the validations being applied.

Comment: Which args do you want to access? `self.name` should return the new name OR the old one ; `self.changes[:name].try(:first)` should return the new name if it was changed, and `self.changes[:name].try(:last)` will return the old name if changed

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it accepts multiple arguments but you can have multiple validations calling the same method.

```
before_validation :foo, :do_something
before_validation :bar, :do_something
before_validation :baz, :do_something
```

Comment: How is the first argument (e.g. `:foo`) referenced in `:do_something`?

Answer (score 0):

```
before_validation :do_something

protected
  def do_something
    #do something here
  end
end
```

[This documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) spells it out pretty clearly.

Comment: I read that.  I was hoping that someone might have a nifty trick, however.

Comment: No nifty trick necessary, you can normalize just fine using this syntax. You'll just need to normalize each independently. So like self.foo = ?